# Populate different dictionaries with Python dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

I would like to compact this syntax to avoid double dictionaries comprehensions (I hope to gain some computing time)

```
d1 = {loc:list(np.sum(data, 0)) for loc, data in dicos.items()}
d2 = {loc:np.nancumsum(list(np.sum(data, 0))) for loc, data in dicos.items()}
```

I have tried this without success

```
d1,d2 = [{loc:list(np.sum(data, 0)),loc:np.nancumsum(list(np.sum(data, 0)))} \
         for loc, data in dicos.items()]
```

Comment: What does "without success" mean? Did you get incorrect results? If you got an error, please [edit] your question and copy the error's full text into it.

Comment: I don't get it if you want 2 different dictionaries you will have to create it 2 times. even if you  are able to do it in one-line the time would of course be same as of 2 line approach

Comment: You cannot construct two dictionaries without two expressions. You might be able to wrap both into some comprehension, but I doubt that would help you much. Do you need to construct `list`s? Without the `list(...)` calls, I suspect you could still gain some performance.

Comment: @venky__ I think they want to avoid iterating over `dicos.items()` twice.

Comment: How long are these operations going to take?  Is this just an academic exercise, or do you have enough data to process that it's worth additional effort?  If you really need to save time, maybe you should use the `multiprocessing` module and run each of these on a separate core in parallel.

Comment: You could abuse a list comprehension: `from operator import setitem; d1={}; d2={}; [setitem(d1, loc, ...), setitem(d2, loc, ...) for loc, data in dicos.items()]`. The resulting list is useless and I doubt is is faster than an explicit `for` loop over `dicos.items()`, though.

Comment: @MattDMo by "without success" mean that d1 =... d2 = ... is not identical to d1,d2 = [...] since the other part of my code is not working anymore

Comment: @steve I parse several covid data base and I would like to optimize my code

Comment: I think you're trying too hard to constrain all of this to a single comprehension.  You'd be better off breaking this code up into a function or two.

Comment: @steve I have tree different dictionnaries which I populate with this syntax. It seems iredundant

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't understand our community's recent obsession with trying to shove more and more functionality into a single comprehension.  Not only is the result usually no more efficient than using visible loops, the code can definitely be much less readable when done as a single, complex comprehension.  I think what people don't understand is that the loop still exists in much the same form either way...it's just that it's hidden from you inside the Python library code if you use a comprehension.

Here's a clean, readable way to do what you want where you only make a single pass over your data, you build the two dictionaries, and it's very clear what you're doing:

```
d1 = {}
d2 = {}
for loc, data in dicos.items():
    d1[loc] = list(np.sum(data, 0))
    d2[loc] = np.nancumsum(list(np.sum(data, 0)))
```